# onkeydown not working, onblur working

Tags: javascript

When I create a text box (input5) dynamically the next function works

```
input5.onblur = function() {validate_quantity(this)}
```

but the next one, doesnt work

```
input5.onkeydown = function() {validateNumbers(event)}
```

When I load the page, I have a first text box in html, with

```
onblur="validate_quantity" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)
```

and BOTH work nice in this first text box, whats wrong with my input5.onkeydown line?

Comment: Please define "working/not working", and show the code for `validate_quantity`.

Comment: with ctrl-alt-j in mozilla it sends me "event is not defined"

Comment: Int HTML it says "onkeydown='return validateNumbers(event)'", instead

Comment: If that's your full code, the missing `()` after `onkeydown = function` is going to be a problem.

Comment: Try this `input5.onkeydown = function() {validateNumbers(event)}`

Comment: function validateNumbers(e) { tecla = {document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which; if (tecla==8) return true; ..........

Comment: it does have the () the onkeydown function , sorry

Comment: Don't use these kind of trigger handlers, they're from a previous era of the web. Use modern event listening instead; I've posted an answer with how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The code you're showing is for highly deprecated JS trigger handling. It's how we did event handling back in the HTML4.01 (1998) era, but it's not how you do event handling in modern HTML and JS.

The modern approach is to use event listening, using the `addEventListener` (and `removeEventListener`) functions in a bit of page script (loaded just before `</body>` so that any elements that need to be found via document.getElementById or document.querySelector can be found):

```
var userInput = document.getElementById("userinput");

function dataHandler(evt) {
  var quantity = userInput.value;
  if (validateQuantity(quantity)) {
    // do things
  }
}

userInput.addEventListener("blur", dataHandler);
userInput.addEventListener("keydown", dataHandler);
```

Comment: dynamically how would be the declaration of the handler?

Comment: I don't know what you mean with that question. You defined your handling function properly, and then you attach to the element that needs to use it as event handler once that element exists and will be ready to generate events.

Comment: I mean something like: input5.addEventListener("blur", validate_quantity);, which is executed when I create the text box with createElement. But it doesnt work. thats why I asked how would it be the code

Comment: I mean, instead of using: input5.onkeydown = function () . . . use: input5.addEventListener("blur", validate_quantity); is this correct? or it has to be donde in another way.